# what's the script to change table column?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Suppose I have a table like Tab(col1 varchar(50), ....)

Then I want to change the column col1 to col1 varchar(100). SQL Server management studio generated script for this task as:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Tmp_Tab
    (
    Col1 varbinary(100) NULL
    )  ON [PRIMARY]
GO
ALTER TABLE dbo.Tmp_Tab SET (LOCK_ESCALATION = TABLE)
GO
IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM dbo.Tab)
     EXEC('INSERT INTO dbo.Tmp_Tab (Col1)
        SELECT Col1 FROM dbo.Tab WITH (HOLDLOCK TABLOCKX)')
GO
DROP TABLE dbo.Tab
GO
EXECUTE sp_rename N'dbo.Tmp_Tab', N'Tab', 'OBJECT' 
GO
```

That's too complicated. Any simple script like Alter table for this kind of change?

Comment: You've asked about `varchar` but the script says `varbinary`. Which is it?

Answer (score 1):

Because changing from varchar(50) to varchar(100) does not require any data conversion, you can just do:

```
alter table Tab
alter column Col1 varchar(100) null;
```

Comment: This could have the undesirable side effect of making the column disallow `null`

Comment: Actually I got that the wrong way round. [From BOL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190273.aspx) `ANSI_NULL` defaults are always on for `ALTER COLUMN`; if not specified, the column is nullable.

Answer (score 0):

From `varbinary(50)` to `varbinary(100)` is just a metadata change

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.Tab ALTER COLUMN Col1 varbinary(100) NULL
```

The same applies to `varchar(50)` to `varchar(100)`